# Power bi create matrix table

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have a table in my powerbi report, but I need to create a matrix table, where the row and column heading are pulled from a distinct set of values from one column and the counts in the cell are a distinct count of another column based on the combination of the row and the column

## Raw Data

```
ROW NAME    AttributeType    Attibute       Attribute Value         
1   John    ID Key           EMAIL          JohnSmith@google.com    
2   Bill    ID Key           EMAIL          Bill@yahoo.com          
3   Sue     ID Key           EMAIL          Sue@google.com          
4   John    ID Key           TWITER         John@google.com         
5   John    ID Key           EMAIL          JohnSmith@google.com    
6   John    ID Key           EMAIL          JohnSmith@google.com    
7   Sue     ID Key           EMAIL          JohnSmith@google.com    
8   John    ID Key           EMAIL          JohnSmith@google.com    
9   Frank   ID Key           EMAIL          Frank@google.com        
10  Frank   ID Key           TWITTER        Frank@google.com        
11  Frank   ID Key           SNAPCHAT       Frank@google.com
```

trying to create the following results:

## Transformed Data to produce the customer counts

```
        EMAIL   TWITTER     SNAPCHAT
EMAIL       1       2           0
TWITTER     2       0           0
SNAPCHAT    0       0           0
```

## How I get the counts

EMAIL / EMAIL = 1 customer, 
                Only Sue since she is the only customer 
                that has EMAIL only

EMAIL / TWITTER = 2 customers, 
                  Bill and John as they have EMAIL and TWITTER Only

EMAIL / SNAPCHAT = 0 No customers have EMAIL and SNAPCHAT only

TWITTER / EMAIL = 2 customers, Bill and John as they 
                  have EMAIL and TWITTER Only

TWITTER / TWITTER = 0 No customers have TWITTER only

TWITTER / SNAPCHAT = 0 No customers have TWITTER and SNAPCHAT only

SNAPCHAT / EMAIL = 0 No customers have SNAPCHAT and EMAIL Only

SNAPCHAT / TWITTER = 0 No customers have SNAPCHAT and TWITTER only

SNAPCHAT / SNAPCHAT = 0 No customers have SNAPCHAT and SNAPCHAT only

Comment: you need it as a new datatable or just as a  visualization?

Comment: ideally both, since the idea here is once I can get the datatable to produce the above results I can then add the appropriate logic to increase the number of colums and to change the calculation related to the qualified record count

Answer (score 0):

You could use a summarized table:

```
Totals = 
     SUMMARIZE('table';
     'table'[Attribute];
     "Email"; calculate(distincount('table'[NAME]), 'table'['Attribute]="EMAIL";
     "TWITTER"; calculate(distincount('table'[NAME]), 'table'['Attribute]="TWITTER";
     "SNAPCHAT"; calculate(distincount('table'[NAME]), 'table'['Attribute]="SNAPCHAT")
```

Comment: here your hardcoding the column name, but this needs to be read from the table as new attributes are added, for example  WEB, I need a way for the columns to read from the table.